# method for recording touch screen inputs for usability study

Tags: android, android-studio

I plan to perform a usability study on an Android app that I created in Android Studios. I would like to record the user touch screen inputs while they navigate through a specific task within the constraints of the application. Is there a method to record these user inputs? This would greatly help me to identify the appropriate size and location of buttons, boxes, etc..

Comment: Why don't any of the many screen recording apps that exist work for you?

Comment: This question is very, very broad. Can you narrow it down to a specific problem with a [MCVE] so you can receive better help?

Comment: I am aware of ways to record the screen and plan to use that  but I also want to record the specific screen touch event locations to determine the most appropriate and intuitive button location and size.